# Gulp: how to find the longest functions in JS code?

Tags: javascript, refactoring, gulp

Is there any gulp plugin to find the longest functions in JavaScript code?

I mean functions that contain a lot of code lines.

I know it probably possible in IDE like VisualStudio or WebStorm, but I want to use gulp or grunt.

Comment: Maybe something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-complexity is what you want? (Lines-of-code is less useful than complexity analysis.)